# Google Charts: How to pass a parameter into a callback (JavaScript)?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a following code:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback( drawChart );
function drawChart() { ... }
```

I need to pass a parameter called chartID into a drawChart() function. How can I do it? Seems google chart doesn't want to get any params :) Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way is to add another function...

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
  drawChart(chartID);
});

function drawChart(chartID) { ... }
```